# Change Colorbox maxWidth option in Backbone.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, handlebars.js, colorbox

I'm using Handlebars.js for HTML template. Like this:

```
    <div class="row">
        {{#ifCond ImagePath '==' "/images/noneImage.jpg"}}
      <div class="col-md-8">
          {{else}}
          <div class="col-md-16">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-16-6">      

              <div class="product-image">
                <img src="//images/{{ImagePath}}" />
              </div>
            </div>
          {{/ifCond}}
...
```

This is my Colorbox template and its working. If product hasn't a picture, get `col-md-8` class. (If has a image, get `col-md-16`)
My Colorbox JS is here:

```
 productDetail.bind('onLoaded', function () {
      productDetailLB = new lightbox({
        html: '<div class="productDetail"></div>',
        className: 'product-detail-lightbox',
        maxWidth: 870,
        height: 500, 
        onComplete: function () {
          productDetail.setElement('.productDetail');
          productDetail.render();
        }
      });
    });
```

But if product hasn't an image, I want `maxWidth: 500`

How can I fix it? Thank you.

Comment: have you tried setting maxWidth as auto or just not setting it?

Comment: When I not setting, its crashed on the page. Not a solution.

Comment: and can you use a conditional to setting maxWidth?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make maxWidth a function that tests if there's an image. If no, return 500, otherwise, return 870.

```
 productDetailLB = new lightbox({
    html: '<div class="productDetail"></div>',
    className: 'product-detail-lightbox',
    maxWidth: function(){
        if ($('.product-image')){
            return 870;
        } else {
            return 500;
        }
    },
    height: 500, 
    onComplete: function () {
      productDetail.setElement('.productDetail');
      productDetail.render();
    }
```

EDIT: Since I don't have a lot of context, no guarantees that this will work.  All I did was test if there is a div element with the class "product-image" using jquery. You should be able to figure out the if statement on your own if it doesn't.

Comment: thank you! Can you give and example if statement? Because I put some code about if but not working.

Comment: Also note that in order for this to work, anytime you want to reference maxWidth, you have to call it (eg. someObject.maxWidth(), not someObject.maxWidth)

Comment: This is the right approach. If howeveer it's not working, try with the dom ready instead of binding 'onLoaded'